# Does "tag" consume less storage space than "field" in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

According to the influxdb official doc https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/key_concepts , tags are indexed.

However, I do not need to filter data with tags when querying. Using the given example in the official doc

```
time    location    scientist   butterflies honeybees
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z    1   langstroth  12  23
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z    1   perpetua    1   30
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z    1   langstroth  11  28
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z    1   perpetua    3   28
2015-08-18T05:54:00Z    2   langstroth  2   11
2015-08-18T06:00:00Z    2   langstroth  1   10
2015-08-18T06:06:00Z    2   perpetua    8   23
2015-08-18T06:12:00Z    2   perpetua    7   22
```

while "location" and "scientist" are tags.

If I change "location" and "scientist" to fields, will influxdb consume more space to storage them in comparison to when they are tags?

Comment: You shouldn't be worried about storage, rather you should look into which one consumes more RAM. Tags consumes more RAM

Answer (score 0):

Influxdb uses line format which is

`measurment,tag1=value1,tag2=value2 field1=value1,field2=value2 timestamp`

So if you convert the tags into fields the number of points will decrease. This will not only reduce the storage space but also the RAM consumption. So it is always better to store the data as fields if you really don't want the usage of tags (you will not be able to include them in the group by clause)

Comment: do you mean to say if it is a tag then the value is even duplicated in field? I doubt that.

Comment: I didn't say that. I just say tags have their own purposes. Consider a system with 4 CPUs and you want to store the CPU usage in influx db. Here cpu1, cpu2, cpu3, cpu4 can be saved as tags since you may need to calculate the mean or Max usage per CPU. These are indexed as well so if your query has this in where then search is faster. But these consume RAM and storage as well. So  my point is if you don't need the purpose of tag then don't store it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

After the measurement for about one month, I found “tag” does consume less storage space than “field” in influxdb.

I have 90 nodes to measure every 2ms and there are 3 tags. The first tag is the name of the node while the second tag is the name of another node. The third tag is a constant. Therefore, there are 8010(=89*90) combinations of tags.

Using the three tags as "tag" consumes about 500GB storage in one month while using them as "field" consumes about 1.2TB.

But I do not know whether my case fits all kinds of situations.